# requests form-urlencoded data

Tags: python, python-requests

UPDATE:

I think I'm a little closer now, if change my data structure to the following and use:

```
urllib.urlencode(data, doseq=True)

data ={'Properties': [('key', 'KeyLength'), ('value', '512')], 'Category': 'keysets', 'Offset': '0', 'Limit': '10'}
```

I now get the following which is a lot closer, but still not quite correct:

```
Category=keysets&Limit=10&Properties=('key', 'KeyLength')&Properties=('value', '512')&Offset=0
```

I'm re-writing this question because I think I know what the problem is, but still don't quite know how to fix it.

I think the problem relates to the fact that the form data I need to send contains form fields with the same name. i.e. the 'Properties'. This is my data structure:

```
data = {'Properties': [{'key': 'KeyLength', 'value': '512'}], 'Category': 'keysets', 'Offset': '0', 'Limit': '100'}
```

and this is how it should appear when received by the web service:

```
Form Data:
  Properties[0][key]:KeyLength
  Properties[0][value]:768
  Category:
  Offset:0
  Limit:100
```

I'm posting using 'requests' this:

```
req = requests.post('http://server1/ws1/api/data/filters/', data=data)
```

However it seems to end up like this:

```
Category=keysets&Limit=100&Properties=('key', 'KeyLength')&Offset=0
```

Instead of like this:

```
Properties[0][key]=KeyLength&Properties[0][value]=768&Category=&Offset=0&Limit=100
```

Can somebody please advise what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Did you try to use `urllib.urlencode({})` ?

Comment: I did, but not sure if I used it correctly. I'll try again

Comment: I just tried urllib.urlencode(data) but this is what I get after its been decoded: Category=keysets&Limit=10&Properties=[{'value': '512', 'key': 'KeyLength'}]&Offset=0

Comment: Getting a bit closer - as per the update above I can now get this: Category=keysets&Limit=10&Properties={'key': 'KeyLength'}&Properties={'value': '512'}&Offset=0. Close but still not quite right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You won't be able to get that directly. From Python Standard Library Manual, Python url encoding works that way : *Convert a mapping object or a sequence of two-element tuples*.

There is no support for exploding list or hash values like you want : you will have to preprocess your data. You could try a function like that :

```
def transform(h, resul = None, kk=None):
    if resul is None:
        resul = {}
    for (k, v) in h.items():
        key = k if kk is None else "%s[%s]" % (kk, k)
        if isinstance(v, list) or isinstance(v, tuple):
            for i, v1 in enumerate(v):
                transform(v1, resul, '%s[%d]' % (key, i))
        elif isinstance(v, dict):
            for i, v1 in v.items:
                transform(v1, resul, '%s[%s]' % (key, i))
        else:
            resul[key] = v
    return resul
```

With you original data structure, it gives :

```
>>> data = {'Properties': [{'key': 'KeyLength', 'value': '512'}], 'Category': 'keysets', 'Offset': '0', 'Limit': '100'}
>>> transform(data)
{'Category': 'keysets', 'Limit': '100', 'Properties[0][key]': 'KeyLength', 'Offset': '0', 'Properties[0][value]': '512'}
```

And then it would be encoded as per your requirements

Comment: Wow - that hard to do - thought requests might have had something to deal with that. Thank you so much, you've saved me from going crazy, your suggestion worked perfectly !

Comment: Thanks, just saved me some time.

Answer (score 0):

It actually seems that the answer contributed by Serge will not play nice with lists embedded down in the tree. (they don't have an `items()` method)

Here's a variation on the idea that's working for me:

```
def flattenForPost(h, resul = None, kk=None):

  if resul is None:
    resul = {}

  if isinstance(h, str) or isinstance(h, bool):
    resul[kk] = h
  elif isinstance(h, list) or isinstance(h, tuple):
    for i, v1 in enumerate(h):
        flattenForPost(v1, resul, '%s[%d]' % (kk, i))
  elif isinstance(h, dict):
    for (k, v) in h.items():
        key = k if kk is None else "%s[%s]" % (kk, k)
        if isinstance(v, dict):
            for i, v1 in v.items():
                flattenForPost(v1, resul, '%s[%s]' % (key, i))
        else:
            flattenForPost(v, resul, key)
  return resul
```